# 3 Variable Linear Dependent Regression (Klein four-group)

Tags: regression, likert, density-estimation

How do I measure the correlation between three variable which are not correlated with each other as pairs, but together form a linearly dependent relationship?

ex: I have three dichotomous variables, Red, Green and Blue. On a psychometric test, people are asked to rate themselves on each scale, +1 for one trait, –1 for the opposite trait, and 0 for undecided. The test may allow fractional values to measure strength of preference.

Red is not correlated with Green,
Green is not correlated with Blue,
Blue is not correlated with Red.

However, all three form a dependent relationship. Theoretically, a person should rate themselves so that R x G x B > 0, meaning only four of the eight possible combinations should be possible.

For reference, here is a graph of the problem. Red, Green, and Blue are the three axes, and the black lines are the ideal regression. Notice that if you were to look at the graph from either the front, top or side, essential projecting the relationship onto a coordinate plane, the regression would make an X and should have an R value of 0. However, in three dimensions, the ideal regression is restrictive as it is only in 4 of the 8 octants.

[image: Regression Graph of Klein Four-Group]

(addition for clarity)

One of these relationships is between these three dichotomies:

T: (+) logical, (–) ethical

EP: (+) static, (–) dynamic

ETP: (+) merry, (–) serious

Theoretically, T x EP x ETP = + , meaning all people who score logical & static should also score as merry, all who score as logical & dynamic score as serious, all who score as ethical and static score as serious, and all who score as ethical & dynamic score as merry. Together, this creates a typology of four types: structural, practical, relational, emotional, each associated with one of these combinations

[image: Possible and Impossible Combinations]

However, in reality, this will not always be the case, some people will test as an impossible combination. I need to know how to measure the strength of this relationship while taking into account how each person rates their strength of preference.

There are two applications of this. The first is to test if the theory is true in its application. Second, if this dependent relationship can be verified to be statistically significant in a clinical setting, it can be used as a parity check for a mass market inventory.

**My question is, how do I measure this relationship and set up the null hypothesis (this is not a linearly dependent relationship)? Also, if this relationship is verified, how do I apply this to an internal parity check?**

I would think this is called a multi-dimensional regression, but if you know its proper name, please share.

Thanks, Andrew